# HRESULT 0x8876086a after front buffer lost

Tags: wpf, directx, directx-9, directx-10

I am using DirectX to render images in unmanaged code and a D3DImage in WPF to host the surface. When the system goes to sleep, the frontBufferLost event is raised. The event is handled and all the resources are destroyed and recreated.

While using Direct3D9 in unmanaged code, everything works properly. Once the event is raised, device is recreated and rendering is performed without any error.

But when I use DirectX10 in engine, since I also need Direct3D9 device for the purpose of Surface queue, I try to delete and recreate both 10 and 9 devices. At this stage, during the GetDeviceCaps call, I always get 0x8876086a which I think is device not available.

Can someone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to usually solve this type of problem is to go into the DirectX Properties control panel, switch to the debug version of DirectX, turn the debug output level all the way up, and then fire up your app. If you watch your output window in Visual Studio when your GetDeviceCaps() call fails, you will hopefully see the problem.

Good luck!